# PHP Passing variables to included file

Tags: php, code-separation

I have a very simple template class that allows me to set some values and then include a template file. The class stores the variables, and the template file can access using $this->variable.

So my question is how should I go about doing this? Or perhaps it'd be better to just assign some variables and then include the template file - that way they don't need to be passed around?

Comment: what you are doing is like mvc architecture you should read more to apply the proper mvc architecture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call [`extract'](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) like this:

```
extract( $this -> variables );
```

on top on your template code, you will be able to refer to `$this -> variables[foo]` as `$foo`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of OO programming is that variables can be bound to a class and used within the context of a class.

So `$this->title` means: use the title variable bound to **this class**.

What you are basically asking is: how do I get back from OO programming to procedural programming. My answer would be: do not do that, try to stick with OO programming.

Comment: The point is that's a true pain to write `<?php echo $this -> title ?>` just to echo a single value out in a template - that's why I'd consider using a templating engine like Twig in order to write just `{{ title }}`.

Comment: With the short_open_tags on it would be `<?= $this->title ?>` for me, thats short enough.